# Javascript regex all names starting with

Tags: javascript, regex, drop-down-menu

I have a javascript function which should populate a select box with all items from an array starting with the letter passed to the function. The only problem I have is that I can't get my regex statement/coding to work. Here is my function:

```
function replaceCompanySelect (letter)
{

var list = document.getElementById("company");  //Declare the select box as a variable
list.options.length=0;  //Delete the existing options

list.options[0]=new Option("Please Select a Company", "0", false, false); //Add the first option in

for(var i=1;i<companies.length;i++)  //For each company in the array
{

    if(companies[i].match("/\b"+letter+"/g") != null && (letter != 'undefined' ||letter != 'undefined'))  //If the company starts with the correct letter and the position's value is not undefined or empty
    {

        alert(companies[i]); //Only used for testing purposes, code should be as above loop to I used to insert the 1st option

    }

}

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not the answer, but a question: why should letter have the value 'undefined' ?

Comment: As the numbers in the array correspond to id numbers directly from the database, there will be some numbers which do not have values

Comment: Are you shure you don't mean `typeof letter == 'undefined'` ? Why do proove it two times? `(letter != 'undefined' ||letter != 'undefined')`

Comment: I didn't mean it twice, that was a copy and paste error, forgot to change the second one :/ ty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, and without RegEx, too:

```
if (companies[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() == letter.toLowerCase()) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually probably more efficient to do without regular expressions (granted, this would count as micro-optimization though...). I would just do something like:

```
if (letter && companies[i][0].toLowerCase() === letter.toLowerCase()) { ... }
```

Comment: I think you might want `companies[i].charAt(0)`, no?

Comment: `.charAt(0)` works, but characters can also be accessed using array accessor syntax (which happens to be shorter).

Comment: @jmar777 `string[index]` is not standard,but `string.charAt(index)` is. Also http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Standards_features#Standards_features could be helpfull.

Comment: Array accessor syntax actually is standard (it just wasn't until ES5). Virtually all JavaScript engines implemented Strings as "Array-like" objects though, so array accessor syntax is safe in pre-ES5 implementations as well. But point taken... if you're targeting an older version of the spec, it's not strictly "standards compliant".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with a regex. You'll just create problems. Something like this would work.

```
var companies  = ["microsoft","apple","google"],
    startsWith = function(arr,match){

        var length = arr.length;

        for(var i=0; i < length; i+=1){

            if(arr[i].toUpperCase().lastIndexOf(match.toUpperCase(), 0) === 0){

                return arr[i];                           
            }

        }
    };

console.log(startsWith(companies,"g")); //=> returns google
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
function foo (letter) {
 var companies  = ["microsoft","apple","google"];
  return companies.filter(function(s) { return s.match(new RegExp(letter,"ig")); });
}

alert(foo("G")); //google
```